# Extracting data from TempData in view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to extract an id in a view from TempData and place it in an Html.Hidden. When I look at the info of my TempData with Debug it does show all the values but Html.Hidden returns an empty value for my id.

```
  @Html.Hidden("idMatch", @TempData["leMatch,idMatch"])
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `@` before `TempData`.

```
@Html.Hidden("idMatch", TempData["leMatch,idMatch"])
```

EDIT : Even with the `@` infront of the `TempData`, it won't show any error and it will render the Hidden element properly.

TempData has a short lifespan and you should only use it during thecurrent and the subsequent requests only. The `Session` object is the backing store for the `TempData` object, and it is destroyed more quickly than a regular session, i.e., immediately after the subsequent request.

I guess your `TempData` become empty in your case. That is the reason it is rendering as empty value in the Hidden field.

I strongly recommend you to use strongly typed **ViewModels** instead of this **`magical`(dynamically typed)** `TempData/Viewdata`. You may use the `HiddenFor` HTML helper method then

```
@model CustomerViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm()){
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CustomerID)

}
```

Comment: I need the TempData because I'm passing the id from a previous action to a strongly typed partial view. e.g. I'm creating the events for a specific game for each player. As I'm calling the event creation partial view with the player id's I am able to pass those but I also want to pass the id from the match which is in an action calling the parent view. My TempData does contain the data when it gets to the view. I'm having trouble getting to it.

Comment: TempData works well with ReDirects only. check this http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications.

Comment: Solved: I passed my TempData the idMatch instead of the whole collection and I'm extracting it with `code`@Html.Hidden("idMatch", TempData["idMatch"])